# Segmentation Fault return in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Program compiles fine, but returns 'segmentation fault' when ran. Please help. thanks. Ignore the other three functions. The program should Fill an array and the print the value in the array, using pointers and pointer arithmetic

```
 #include <stdio.h>

void FillArray ( int *array, int size );
void PrintArray ( int *array, int size );
//void BubbleSort ( int *array, int size );
//void SelectionSort ( int *array, int size );
//void Swap ( int *x, int *y );

#define SIZE 20

int main (void)
{
    int NumList [SIZE];
    FillArray(NumList, SIZE);
    PrintArray (NumList, SIZE);

}

void PrintArray (int *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \t", *(array+i));
    }
}

void FillArray(int *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        *(array+i)= rand()%101;     
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? This is an easy one.

Comment: You should use tools like valgrind to detect memory leaks.

Comment: "Ignore the other three functions." You should remove extraneous stuff before posting instead of telling us to ignore it, which is just lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array contain only 20 entries but you tried to access invalid entries whose indexes were from 20 to 99.

Comment: Why say 21 to 99? Why not 0 to 99 (all the indices accessed) or 20 to 99 (all the invalid ones accessed)?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying accesing out-of-bound elements. Here is a quick fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 100

void FillArray ( int *array, int size );
void PrintArray ( int *array, int size );

int main (void)
{
    int NumList [SIZE];
    FillArray(NumList, SIZE);
    PrintArray (NumList, SIZE);
}

void PrintArray (int *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \t", array[i]);
    }
}

void FillArray(int *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 101;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access out-of-bound elements. Here is the right way to do it.
Although you pass size of array as another argument, instead of using it, you're using a larger size of 100 which is hard coded.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void FillArray ( int *array, int size );
void PrintArray ( int *array, int size );

#define SIZE 20

int main (void)
{
    int NumList [SIZE];
    FillArray(NumList, SIZE);
    PrintArray (NumList, SIZE);

}

void PrintArray (int *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \t", *(array+i));
    }
}

void FillArray(int *array, int size)
{
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(array+i)= rand()%101;     
    }

    return;
}
```